# Arduino-esque serial output on a PIC16

Tags: microcontroller, pic16f

Got the PIC16LF1939 from a disposable smoke detector to blink an LED.

I'd like to run an NQUEENS and Game of Life program on it to see how it compares to the ATMEGA328P.

Does MPLAB X IDE have TTL (or is it UART? The 5v one, not the -12v/+12v one) serial port subroutines in it's libraries, or will I have to either look an implementation up or "bankroll" my own?

Yes, I know I need a USB TTL serial port adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It reads (on the second page because all the features did not fit on the first page) on the PIC16LF1939 data sheet:

Yes, it has an UART.

Usually IDEs are for writing code and do not contain libraries themselves. The whole environment may have installed an IDE and libraries.

Even if it has libraries, it would have libraries for the UART. Whether you use TTL levels or RS232 levels with the UART is up to your hardware, not the software library.

Comment: I was referencing included libraries that the compiler would link your program against. Thank you though!